# Mysql - Create view combined 2 tables but only merged by select without merge tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have 2 tables, named `table_rebate` and `table_bonus`

`table_rebate` ( have 3 same columns, 2 different columns )

```
a_id     a_value           a_time
 1        1000      2018-05-05 10:25:15
 2        3000      2018-05-05 11:35:15
```

`table_bonus` ( have 3 same columns, 3 different colums )

```
b_id     b_value           b_time      
 01        500       2018-05-05 11:20:15
 02        700       2018-05-05 12:30:15
```

I need to select that 3 same columns into 1 tables to my PHP (CI) views.

```
Number    from       Values            Time
  1      Rebate       1000      2018-05-05 10:25:15
  2      Bonus         500      2018-05-05 11:20:15
  3      Bonus         700      2018-05-05 11:35:15
  4      Rebate       3000      2018-05-05 12:30:15
```

How can I do this ? It's not to be merged,  but need to print like merged table and can be sort by (a_time & b_time) ascending.

```
EXPLAIN select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, `from`, `values`, `time`
from ((select 'rebate' as `from`, a_value as `values`, a_time as `time`
       from table_rebate
      ) union all
      (select 'bonus' as `from`, b_value, b_time
       from table_bonus
      ) 
     ) br cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by `time`;
```

[image]

Comment: I had a same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, `from`, `values`, `time`
from ((select 'rebate' as `from`, a_value as `values`, a_time as `time`
       from table_rebate
      ) union all
      (select 'bonus' as `from`, b_value, b_time
       from table_bonus
      ) 
     ) br cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by `time`;
```

Note that `from`, `values`, and `time` are all keywords in SQL (even if not reserved).  That makes them very bad names for columns.

Comment: For `table_bonus` shoud I declare `b_value as 'values'` and `b_time as 'time'` ? and I'm sorry, what is `@rn` ? Thank you Gordon.

Comment: Because I need to joining 4 tables, is `@rn` will work for 4 tables ?

Comment: @Cendana . . . Yes.  You may need to use an additional subquery with `order by` to get the ordering right.

Comment: Thank you very much gordon, I will try to combine that.

Comment: is selecting use `union all` will result an explain all NULL ?

Comment: @Cendana . . . I don't understand your question.  This will not result in any extra `NULL` values.

Comment: can you check the explain result on my question, Gordon ? is the `union all` query will always give the explain result like that ? thank you